# Is Go SQLCMD slower than windows-native version?

Tags: sql-server, go, sqlcmd

I have been using the windows-native `sqlcmd` to run scripts on my local SQL Server database. I have a set of script files that will create the database, add tables and indices, populate domain data, add sprocs, etc. Running the scripts is done executing a single `sqlcmd -i <file>.sql` per file. This worked well and was fast enough.
After switching to the new Go implementation of `sqlcmd` the database build time is several times slower.

I have not been able to find any way to get timing-type statistics from `sqlcmd` to determine if it is connection issues, connection pooling or other problems. I can see what looks like an improvement if I pass multiple files as additional `-i <file.sql>` options which suggests to me that it is an issue with either the startup of the Go command or the establishment of the initial DB connection.

I did a test where I took ten of my SQL files and I ran them as ten separate `sqlcmd` executions and also as one `sqlcmd` execution with the ten files as separate `-i` input files. The separate commands took 20 seconds, the all-in-one took four. So it would appear be to an issue with startup-overhead or connection overhead.

As suggested by @siggemannen, I tested connections using my AD credentials and a direct DB user. The AD credentials are significantly slower than the direct DB connection implying that is the root of the slowness I am seeing in my scenario.

I am looking for any suggestions or ideas either to solve the problem or to troubleshoot it further. Can anything be done to speed up the AD authentication?

Comment: Why wouldn't a natively written sqlcmd be faster than a custom solution made in Go.  sqlcmd might also connect via some faster method. Do your scripts contains GOs and other non-sql constructs? I'm guessing the parsing code of the GO runtime is just slower

Comment: @siggemannen [go-sqlcmd](https://github.com/microsoft/go-sqlcmd) is a Microsoft product, it's not a "custom" solution. I would not be surprised if it replaces the old `sqlcmd` at some point in the future, as it's under active development, where as the old one gets very little "love" these days.

Comment: Well, that doesn't mean the code is good/fast? If anything, ms had a lot of years to trim the original version.

Comment: It certainly has a lot of improvements, I'll give it that.

Comment: I remember the old version hated question marks within nested long comments, or was it ssms. So yeah, hopefully that is fixed at least :)

Comment: @siggemannen Yeah, my scripts contain GOs and other non-SQL constructs, and I am not too surprised that the Go version might be slightly slower. But it is 4 or 5 times slower in my use case which seems excessive.

Comment: Yeah agree, how many scripts /mbs do you have? You could perhaps add some tracing code in your scripts and then compare the runtime to see if any of the scripts stand out particularly. Does it make a difference if you run with sql user vs windows auth?

Comment: @siggemannen My 10 files are 11kb total, so very small. You are onto something with the auth though. If I run as windows auth my 10 files take 20 seconds, if i use a SQL user they take 2 seconds. I need to be Windows Auth to create the DB though, but I could switch to user-auth after.

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense, the java jdbc driver is very slow creating first connection via windows auth, probably because of all the JNI stuff that needs to start up. I suspect GO has similar penalties for loading native DLLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Go `sqlcmd` is not really slower than the native version. The use of the Windows/AD credentials to establish a connection adds to the startup time it takes when establishing a connection, and as the use case runs a SQL file per `sqlcmd` instance that extra overhead adds up.

We could rework the build scripts to run many SQL files per individual `sqlcmd` and that would restore the performance we need. However, an alternative we can use without any rework is to connect using the [SQL Server-level principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/principals-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) `sa` that is created when the database is created. This restores performance equivalent to the native `sqlcmd` using the AD login.